# What is the website created by Walden?

Tags: two-and-a-half-men

In Two and a Half Men, Walden is an internet billionaire because Microsoft had bought his site and used it for their iPod killer, Zune, earning him a billion dollar bank account! What was this site he created?

Comment: It was called BlunGoGo.com, but I don't think it's ever made clear what its purpose was, at least not at first. I guess it's beside the point since it was bundled with the Zune (somehow).

Comment: Yeah, it would have made sense to ignore if it was a couple of million. But what he got is a billion for it. So, isn't it worth knowing what it was ?

Comment: These days?  A billion is less of a big deal than a million used to be.  Now, if he had gotten a trillion.... THAT'D be something.  A billion?  Meh.

Comment: @Walt: I'dd at that as an answer. There's nothing more about it online. That's it

Comment: Some info here: http://www.fictionurl.com/blungogo-com/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I wrote in the comments, the site was called BlunGoGo. [It's explained in the season 9 opener](http://en.wikiquote.org/wiki/Two_and_a_Half_Men#Nice_to_Meet_You.2C_Walden_Schmidt_.5B9.01.5D):

> Alan: So, just out of curiosity, how does someone get to be worth so much money?
>
> Walden: Well, it's pretty simple really. You ever hear of BlunGogo.com?
>
> Alan: No.
>
> Walden: You never will, because Microsoft bought it from me for $1.3 Billion. Then they bundled it with their "iPod killer," the [Zune](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zune).

...and to the best of my knowledge, that's unfortunately all we know about it.